# Как добавить кликабельную ссылку на репозиторий, а под ней разместите краткое описание?

Tags: javascript, html, ссылка

Создаем поисковик с поиском репозиториев на Github.

```
const form = document.querySelector('.search__form');
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector('.search__findings-list');
const countContainer = document.querySelector('.search__findings');
const errorContainer = document.querySelector('.search__error');


const renderError = () => {
  errorContainer.innerHTML = `
        <img src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/entrance-test/search.svg" alt="" class="search__error-icon" />
        <p class="search__error-message">
            Произошла ошибка...
        </p>
  `;
  countContainer.innerHTML = '';
};

const renderEmptyResults = () => {
  errorContainer.innerHTML = `
        <img src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/entrance-test/search.svg" alt="" class="search__error-icon" />
        <p class="search__error-message">
            По вашему запросу ничего не найдено, попробуйте уточнить запрос
        </p>
  `;
  countContainer.innerHTML = '';
};

const renderCount = count => {
  countContainer.innerHTML = `
      Найдено <span class="search__findings-amount">${count.toLocaleString(
        'ru-RU'
      )}</span> результатов
  `;
};

const onSubmitStart = () => {
  countContainer.innerHTML = `Загрузка...`;
  resultsContainer.innerHTML = '';
  errorContainer.innerHTML = '';
};

function template(item) {
  const newElement = document.createElement('li');
  newElement.classList.add('search__finding-item');
  newElement.innerHTML = `
      <a class="search__finding-link" target="_blank" >
          ${item.full_name}
      </a>
    `;
  return newElement;
}

async function onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  onSubmitStart();
  await fetch(
    `https://api.nomoreparties.co/github-search?q=${event.target.elements['title'].value}`
  )
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
      const { items, total_count } = data;
      if (total_count) {
        renderCount(total_count);
        items.forEach(item => resultsContainer.appendChild(template(item)));
      } else {
        renderEmptyResults();
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      renderError();
    });
}

form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);


 **Необходимо добавить кликабельную ссылку на репозиторий, а под ней разместите краткое описание. Дописать функцию шаблонизации результатов поиска template.При успешном запросе поиска для каждого найденного репозитория:**

    {
        total_count: 325299
        incomplete_results: false
        items: [
            {
                id: 20929025,
                name: "TypeScript",
                full_name: "microsoft/TypeScript",
                html_url: "https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript",
                description: "TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that compiles to clean JavaScript output.",
                stargazers_count: 79871,
                language: "TypeScript",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

Поле c описанием (description) оберните тегом .

Никак не получается.

Answer (score 0):

```
function template(item) {
///
  newElement.innerHTML = `
      <a class="search__finding-link" href="${item.html_url}">
          ${item.full_name}
      </a>
      <span class="search__finding-description">${item.description}</span>
    `;
 ///
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]